# Correct sequence of starting async operations and running io_service in boost::asio?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm trying to understand the correct sequence of starting the io_service `io_service::run()` vs. the first async operation in my application, for example, `async_accept`. Most boost examples seem to do the latter first, not sure why.

The [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html) makes the following point:

> Your program must make a call to io_service::run() in order for the result to be
>   retrieved. A call to io_service::run() blocks while there are
>   unfinished asynchronous operations, so you would typically call it as
>   soon as you have started your first asynchronous operation.

I understand from the diagram that the results of async operations are communicated to io_service via a queue and unless the io_service is already running it won't pick up the results from this queue. So isn't it correct to say that the io_service should always be started first. The doc seems to imply otherwise. Can someone please explain ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asynchronous operation like `async_accept` will start the async task in the OS, which will put the result (as soon as available) into the `io_service`'s event queue.

`io_service::run` will poll the queue for results and invoke your handlers passing those results.

When you have no asynchronous tasks, there are no results to fetch for the `io_service` and there is also no *outstanding work* that might produce any results, so it simply returns.

So, the order you want is:

- start atleast one asynchronous task
- call `io_service::run` to initiate the polling

You can even start a single async task that may initiate a whole *chain* of tasks and never have the `io_service` run out of work to do.